# Setting UFW permissions

Tags: permissions, ip, ipv6, ufw

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I just activated UFW set the following permissions. Basically only allowing HTTP, HTTPS and email as well as DNS out.
In checking the log, I see the the kernel is being blocked out by UFW. How do I correct this so the kernel can do it's thing?

Does `localhost` need to be opened?

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

This is my table:

```
To                      Action    From
----------------------- --------- -------------
Anywhere                DENY  IN  Anywhere    
53/udp                  ALLOW OUT Anywhere
80,443,587,993/tcp      ALLOW OUT Anywhere
Anywhere                DENY OUT  Anywhere
53/udp (v6)             ALLOW OUT Anywhere (v6)
80,443,587,993/tcp (v6) ALLOW OUT Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6)           DENY OUT  Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: What do you mean that the "kernel" is being "blocked out"?

Comment: This is one line in the ufw log file. There are hundreds of them. ---- Jun  9 08:29:54 Power-System kernel: [ 3327.256676] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC=40:b0:76:42:83:fe:48:f8:b3:23:be:94:08:00 SRC=173.241.244.220 DST=192.168.1.143 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=36942 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41376 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0

Comment: Buy the way 173.241.244.220 is the IP for: " OpenX Technologies, Inc. provides digital and mobile advertising technology products and services to digital media companies"  Another IP I checked is for Amazon. Why would the "kernel" be doing this?

Comment: Because the kernel is where the firewall is. Anyway that's a final RST being spuriously blocked. It's harmless.

Comment: OK, I'm glad to hear it's harmless. Do you know of any ports Ubuntu needs to have open or is it all good blocking OUT as far as the operating system goes?